# jQueryのmodaal.jsで紐付けができない

Tags: jquery

aタグを使わずにbuttonでやると紐付けができないのですが、どなたかご教示いただけると嬉しいです。

```
<button class="js-modal" data-group="gallery"　data-modaal-content-source="#content01">表示</button>
<button class="js-modal" data-group="gallery"　data-modaal-content-source="#content02">表示</button>
<button class="js-modal" data-group="gallery"　data-modaal-content-source="#content03">表示</button>

<div id="js-modal" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
      <li id="content01">コンテンツ</li>
　　　　　　　　　　　　<li id="content02">コンテンツ</li>
　　　　　　　　　　　　<li id="content03">コンテンツ</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
$('.js-modal').modaal();
</script>
```

現状、なぜか全てひとまとめに全部li要素が出てしまいます。
content01が出てればcontent02,content03は出ない様にしたいです。
それぞれのボタンタグからはcontentで結びつけた物が出る様にしたい。

色々探してみたもののこれと言ってよくわからなかったです・・・

Comment: 紐付けってどういうことですか？ 「aタグを使わずにbuttonでやると紐付けができない」ということは、a タグを使えばやりたいことができると言っているようですが、であればそのコードを提示してください。